# Is it possible to record a .webm file using gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, video-capture, webm

I'd like to record a `.webm` file beside my main `.mkv` file to serve, that `.webm` file, to a video object on html page to read from (kind of simple streaming just to see what it's recording)

I'm using pipeline below (with tee for this purpose) to record from my webcam:

```
gst-launch-1.0  v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! tee name=t t. \
! image/jpeg,width=1920,height=1080 ! capssetter \
caps='image/jpeg,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1' ! queue \
! matroskamux name=mux pulsesrc device="alsa_input.usb-046d_Logitech_Webcam_C930e_AAF8A63E-02-C930e.analog-stereo" \ 
! 'audio/x-raw,channels=1,rate=44100' ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! queue \
! mux. mux. ! filesink location=/home/sina/Desktop/Recordings/Webcam.mkv \ 
t. ! queue ! (...pipeline?...) ! filesink location=/home/sina/Desktop/Recordings/TestWebcam.webm
```

How should I fill the pipeline for the last line?(what structure?  encoder? muxer? ...)

Comment: You want .webm file to be without audio?

Comment: yes, only the video, audio is not important, just to be played using video object on html UI while being recorded

Comment: As I understood, you want to put stream of JPEGs to your .mkv file, correct? Why?

Comment: I want it to be MJPEG because that's the only format my webcam offers for HD recording, but the .webm is  not so important with regard to format or quality, just need a playable file for it (FYI, first part of my pipeline works fine, I'm stuck on the second part)

Answer (score 0):

While it's still possible to convert stream of JPEG pictures to `.WebM` with VP8 stream inside, it will be consuming operation and results will not be pretty: encoding→decoding→encoding sequence will spoil output bad (and use more CPU).

If you don't need JPEGs and don't care about video format inside `.mkv` file, easiest solution will be to use single VP8 encoder (because both `.mkv` and `.webm` files can contain VP8) and split encoded streams:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
    v4l2src ! vp8enc ! tee name=t ! \
        queue ! matroskamux name=m ! filesink location=1.mkv \
        pulsesrc ! vorbisenc ! m. \
    t. ! \
        queue ! webmmux ! filesink location=1.webm
```

Also, make sure you use `-e` option to force EOS when you terminate command via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

GStreamer WebM muxer is very tiny layer over Matroska muxer: `.webm` is almost equal to `.mkv`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! but the video format is important for me, it needs to be MJPEG (it's because my webcam offeres HD capturing only with MJPEG considering this fact that I want the final result to be 1080P) on the other hand, the format of .webm is not so important (just need a playable file via a html video object) first part of my pipeline works fine but when I added vp8enc + webmmux to the second part (for .webm) it failed to negotiate the format... do you have any suggestion on this?